# VBS script to remove accounts from Administrators group

Tags: vbscript

I found a script online the other day that removes users from the Administrators group that are not supposed to be there.

```
 strComputer = "localhost"

Set objGroup = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/Administrators")

For Each objUser In objGroup.Members
If objUser.Name <> "Administrator" AND objUser.Name <> "Domain Admins"  AND objUser.Name <> "Help Desk Admins" Then
    objGroup.Remove(objUser.AdsPath)
End If
Next
```

It works successfully for any account that appears in the list like this: domain\username, but will not delete them if they show up as domain\username (S-1-5-21-178213213-343423442-23423432-23423).

How can I make this force out the ones that have the long numbers at the end?

Thanks!